# Does anyone know how to configure grunt-gcloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, gruntjs, gcloud

Does anyone know how to configure [grunt-gcloud](https://github.com/ubilabs/grunt-gcloud)?

This is the default example that is provided, but I can't figure out how to use it...

```
grunt.initConfig({
  gcloud: {
    options: {
      projectId: 'MyAwesomeProject',
      bucket: 'bucket',
      keyFilename: '.gcloud.json'
    },
    files: [{
      src: [
        'dist/**/*'
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

All suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Zachary Newman:  grunt-gcloud has nothing to do with the Google Cloud Client Library for Node.js...

Comment: Have you configured and used other grunt tasks before? Are you seeing an error when you run it? If you have [grunt-cli](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) installed, you should just be able to run `grunt gcloud` in your console...

Comment: @SkipJack Yes, I've been using Grunt since 2014, and it is just `grunt gcloud` that is causing me problems right now. I'll post the error I get in a bit.

Comment: @iamchriswick Is this still an issue? Are you still experiencing this? If not, could you share your findings?